# Should I npmignore ".github" folder?

Tags: github, npm, npmignore

Should I npmignore `.github` folder which contains stuff need for Github Actions?

Also side question. Do I need to push `.npmignore` to github?

Answer (score 0):

If .github folder is used for github, I think you should push it on the repo. Concerning .npmignore files, it's useful to push it or if you clone your repo on another place, it will not be available on his npm command.

Hope it helps

Comment: `.github` folder already pushed to github, I'm asking if I should publish it to npm or add it to `.npmignore` to prevent it from publishing.

Comment: Usually the stuff in .github is specific to the repository you use (templates, etc.) so I'd personally ignore it but I'm sure there are scenarios where that's desired behavior.